# How to fit CSS buttons into table cells?

Tags: html, css

I would like to put CSS buttons into several tables. Ideally, each button should fill the corresponding table cell. This presents a problem because if I hard-code the button width in CSS, I would need a separate class for each table dimension.

Is there a way to have the buttons fit into the table cells?

HTML:

```
<center>

 <table border="1" width="90%" class="buttons">
<tr>
<td width="25%"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link1 goes here</a></td>
<td width="25%"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link2<br>goes<br>here</a></td>
<td width="25%"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link3<br>goes<br>here</a></td>
<td width="25%"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link4<br>goes<br>here</a></td>
</tr>
</table> 

<p>

<table border="1" width="90%" class="buttons">
<tr>
<td width="20%"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link1 goes here</a></td>
<td width="20%"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link2<br>goes<br>here</a></td>
<td width="20%"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link3<br>goes<br>here</a></td>
<td width="20%"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link4<br>goes<br>here</a></td>
<td width="20%"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link5<br>goes<br>here</a></td>
  </table>

</center>
```

CSS:

```
.buttons
{
overflow:auto;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.0em;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 200%;

}

.buttons a
{
display: inline-block;
width: 18em;
height: 6em;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
padding-top: .6em;
padding-bottom: .6em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #aaabbb;
border-radius: 5px;
border: solid #cccccc 1px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888888;
clear:right;
float:right;
}

.buttons a:active
{
box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #888888;
}
```

Play with the code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bIEtC

Comment: Why are you using tables and not divs? Out of curiosity.

Comment: I need 4, 5 or 6 buttons in 1 or 2 rows. They should be evenly spaced. I would love to do this without tables, just not sure how. Do you think that would also solve the problem stated in my question?

Comment: In my opinion, using div's instead of tables will give you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Probably. Do you have a link to some good code examples for that?

Comment: Probably the most informative: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try to set height and width 100%. Like this:

```
.buttons a
{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;       /* set to 100% */
   height: 100%;      /* set to 100% */
   margin-bottom: 0.5em;
   padding-top: .6em;
   padding-bottom: .6em;
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #aaabbb;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: solid #cccccc 1px;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888888;
   clear:right;
   float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try not to hard code CSS into the HTML... it leads to a mess of trouble!

Taking the inline styling out of the html seems to fix most problems.  Then, just like @ArmanVirdi said, add the width and the height of the link to be 100%.

The `<center>` tags don't seem to be doing anything, so those are removed in the below HTML, as well as an unclosed `<p>` tag.

## HTML

```
<table class="buttons width-25">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Link1 goes here</a>

            </td>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Link2<br>goes<br>here</a>

            </td>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Link3<br>goes<br>here</a>

            </td>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Link4<br>goes<br>here</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="buttons width-20">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Link1 goes here</a>

            </td>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Link2<br>goes<br>here</a>

            </td>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Link3<br>goes<br>here</a>

            </td>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Link4<br>goes<br>here</a>

            </td>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Link5<br>goes<br>here</a>

            </td>
    </table>
```

---

## CSS

```
table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .width-20 td {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .width-25 td {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .buttons {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.0em;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 200%;
    }
    .buttons a {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
        padding-top: .6em;
        padding-bottom: .6em;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #aaabbb;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: solid #cccccc 1px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888888;
    }
    .buttons a:active {
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #888888;
    }
```

[JSFiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/3acb6/)

Comment: This (using classes) is not always useful. Especially for email html. For the safest html to get emails to look correct you pretty much have no choice but to use inline css. I say "safest" because some enterprise systems do not allow head tags or style tags.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `.buttons`:

```
width:0;
```

Resut:

[image]